# Why do we create private properties in .m file when same work done by simple instance variable in iOS?

Tags: ios, properties, private, instance-variables

I know creating a private property of any instance say

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSString * mystring
```

in implementation file will just  create it privately and won't be visible outside the class. It can be accessed within the same class or file. SO my question is why we create properties for those insatnce as we can simply create a private instance variable like this

```
@Private NSString * mystring;
```

even this won't be accessible outside the class. Why do we create private properties as creating simple private instance serve the p? any help to clear my concept is appreciated.. Thanks!

Comment: First, *nothing* is really private in Objc. Second, what properties do additionally to just creating a backing space for the ivar is providing getters and setters (depending on its attributes). Usually you should never access an instance variable directly (not even inside the class it is declared in) except for `init` methods and the property's accessor methods, of course. To not access a variable from outside the class directly is to encapsulate the attribute. To not access it from inside the class (very rarely you actually *need* to access them directly) is for getting KVC/KVO behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second case creates just a variable, whereas the first case creates a property. A property consists of getter and setter methods, which operate on the associated variable that is automatically created for you.

Example:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)  NSString *name; //declaration of property

// this creates behind the scenes a variable,
NSString *_name;

// a getter,
-(NSString *) name {
   return _name;
}

// and a setter
-(void) setName:(NSString *)name {
   [_name release];
   _name = nil;
   _name = [name copy];
}
```

When you do `myObject.name = @"James"`, the `setName:` method above is invoked automatically, and the code inside the method is executed. In contrast, if you had declared the property `name` as a simple variable, it would be just that - there would be no method call under the hood and no additional code executed.

Note that the setter created automatically for you takes care of the reference counting and the copying of the string, as you requested in the declaration of the property. The other keyword that you specified (`nonatomic`) also affects the auto generated code, and governs whether your property is thread-safe or not.

You can override the setter or the getter of an auto-generated property, to add additional functionality. For example, you can override the setter of the `name` property above, to capitalize the first letter before the passed value is copied.

Lastly, using properties instead of simple variables allows your code to utilize the Objective-C infrastructure by allowing it to integrate with KVC/KVO and other such functionality.

Comment: thanks mate but I already know that what happens when we create a property i.e about getter and setter. but I don'y understand that if i had a NSString property say name and simple iVar NSString * lastname then what would be effect on my code with follow :
       obj.name = @"Russia";
    lastname  = @"XYZ";

Comment: can you give me some hint that how should I use private ivars and private properties with some code?

Comment: The effect of doing `lastname = @"XYZ";` as in your comment above, would be that the string value would not be copied, and so when the local `NSAutoreleasePool` was deallocated, the string Object instance with value "XYZ" that ivar `lastname` was pointing to, would also be deallocated. The next time you tried to access `lastname`, you application would crash. This wouldn't be a problem if that ivar was of a different type (i.e., a primitive), but in any case you wouldn't benefit from encapsulation, KVC/KVO functionality, etc.